# how to make header of panel in UWP in c#

Tags: c#, uwp

Hi everyone does anybody know how to make the header like the image "pizza size":
[image]

I found in control in UWP (Universal windows platform) but I could not find it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There are controls like **Pivot** and **Hub** with the headers built in.. Optionally you can achieve this in different ways.. one of them is to define a grid and add row definitions to it..something like this ..

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Textblock Text="Pizza Size" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5">
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1">
        <RadioButton Content="Small"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Medium"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Large"/>            
 </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/design-and-ui-intro) to design and UI introduction for UWP apps to get you started ! Hope this helps..